# If product titles are similar to category title, how does it affect SEO?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, ecommerce

Let's say I have a product title of

"Long Sleeve Shirts"

Will it be okay if my products' titles are

- Children long sleeve shirts
- Family long sleeve shirts
- Couple long sleeve shirts

So every product has the same "Long sleeve shirts" as the category title.

Will this affect the ranking of the category page and product pages?

If the product is only "Children" "Family" "Couple", will they still also rank for "Children long sleeve shirts" and so on?

Answer (score 1):

You talk about two different thing, product titles and category titles, and used them as the same thing in your example.

You should make your product names as unique as possible. It's OK if the *category* is the same (because that is what a category does), but the *product* title should be unique.

Example which are fine:

```
Category                       Productname (this is what holds the SEO value)
Children long sleeve shirts -> Bright blue cartoon T-shirt
Children long sleeve shirts -> Flashy pink pony T-shirt
Children long sleeve shirts -> Happy squirrels friends T-shirt
```

---

If you have this:

```
Category              Productname (this is what holds the SEO value)
Long sleeve shirts -> Children long sleeve shirts 
Long sleeve shirts -> Family long sleeve shirts
Long sleeve shirts -> Couple long sleeve shirts
```

You still have unique titles, but they're very alike and I would not recommend this. It will not hurt you (as long as your content is unique), but it isn't very good either.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. What I meant was

"If the product titles are similar to the category title, will that affect SEO"

For example the Category is "Long Sleeve Shirt"

Is it okay if the product name is "Children Long Sleeve Shirt"

The only difference between the 2 titles is "Children".

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem. We have 'insurance' as a category and 'car insurance' as a product page. We rank very well for both terms.